# Changing nested element of an atom

Tags: clojure

I am trying to change value of an atom:

`#atom[{{:other-site-conf 2499/2500, :own-unconf|other-conf [[30.752499999999998 1.0126843266559153 12] "Humidity"], :other-site-unconf 1/2500, :both-unconf [[27.563987107797804 4.984857204039122 7511] "Humidity"], :site-id 1, :other-site-quant 0.86235090749618} {:other-site-conf 2497/2500, :own-unconf|other-conf [[22.976875 0.09445843442135488 4] "Temperature"], :other-site-unconf 3/2500, :both-unconf [[20.920551354838697 1.0618445458730512 7511] "Temperature"], :site-id 0, :other-site-quant 0.7673990631272951}} 0x5bf8ef86]`

In this I want to change map values inside :both-unconf of second map that is of :site-id 0

I have tried using:

```
(swap! prob-cond update-in [1 1 :both-unconf 1 1 0] 22)
```

but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass swap! a function.
`(swap! prob-cond #(update-in % [1 1 :both-unconf 1 1 0] (constantly 22))`

Comment: Thanks for reply but still there is error. Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException
   java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Comment: Sorry, updated the answer. Replace `(constantly 22)` with a function that takes the value you want to replace, and returns a new value.

Comment: When I changed the code to :(swap! prob-cond #(update-in % [1 1 :both-unconf 1 1 0] (updated-mean (get y 0) value-in-record (get y 2))
                             )),                                                                        
 Still got the error:Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException
   java.lang.Double cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Comment: When I use (constantly 22) then I am getting , 1 {1 {:both-unconf {1 {1 {1 22}}}}} added up at the end.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `update-in`. It takes a collection (the atom value, in this case), a vector of keys and a function that takes the value of the key and returns a new value.  
Try replacing `(updated-mean (get y 0) value-in-record (get y 2))` with `(fn [val] (updated-mean (get y 0) val (get y 2)))`

Comment: I have tried this,but the val value is not reaching in the function ,it is printing nil there ,therefore throwing null pointer exception.I think there is some problem with vector of keys ,can you please check that.

Comment: No,I am not getting the results,I think there is some problem with vector of keys.I don't know why instead of updating it is appending some new value at the end.I am not even able to update :both-unconf instead of nesting inside it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.It helped me in reaching the final result.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a mistake with your data, I believe:

```
(def data
  {{:other-site-conf       2499/2500,
    :own-unconf|other-conf [[30.752499999999998 1.0126843266559153 12] "Humidity"],
    :other-site-unconf     1/2500,
    :both-unconf           [[27.563987107797804 4.984857204039122 7511] "Humidity"],
    :site-id               1,
    :other-site-quant      0.86235090749618}
   {:other-site-conf       2497/2500,
    :own-unconf|other-conf [[22.976875 0.09445843442135488 4] "Temperature"],
    :other-site-unconf     3/2500,
    :both-unconf           [[20.920551354838697 1.0618445458730512 7511] "Temperature"],
    :site-id               0,
    :other-site-quant      0.7673990631272951}}
  )
```

Here `data` is a map with a single MapEntry.  Both the key and value of this MapEntry are, in turn maps.  This is almost certainly not what you wanted.

I am assuming you wanted to have a `vector` containing 2 maps, like so:

```
(def data
  [{:other-site-conf       2499/2500,
    :own-unconf|other-conf [[30.752499999999998 1.0126843266559153 12] "Humidity"],
    :other-site-unconf     1/2500,
    :both-unconf           [[27.563987107797804 4.984857204039122 7511] "Humidity"],
    :site-id               1,
    :other-site-quant      0.86235090749618}
   {:other-site-conf       2497/2500,
    :own-unconf|other-conf [[22.976875 0.09445843442135488 4] "Temperature"],
    :other-site-unconf     3/2500,
    :both-unconf           [[20.920551354838697 1.0618445458730512 7511] "Temperature"],
    :site-id               0,
    :other-site-quant      0.7673990631272951}
   ])
```

You can change the value like so:

```
  (let [state (atom data)
        result (swap! state #(assoc-in % [1 :both-unconf 0 0] 42)) ]
```

with result:

```
[{:other-site-conf 2499/2500,
  :own-unconf|other-conf
  [[30.752499999999998 1.0126843266559153 12] "Humidity"],
  :other-site-unconf 1/2500,
  :both-unconf
  [[27.563987107797804 4.984857204039122 7511] "Humidity"],
  :site-id 1,
  :other-site-quant 0.86235090749618}
 {:other-site-conf 2497/2500,
  :own-unconf|other-conf
  [[22.976875 0.09445843442135488 4] "Temperature"],
  :other-site-unconf 3/2500,
  :both-unconf [[42 1.0618445458730512 7511] "Temperature"],
  :site-id 0,
  :other-site-quant 0.7673990631272951}]
```

Comment: I am having the same structure that I have mentioned in the question.                     using this:  (swap! prob-cond #(assoc-in % [1 :both-unconf 0 0] 42))                           is giving :1 {:both-unconf {0 {0 42}}} at the end of structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your top level data structure is a map. So when you do `assoc-in` (or `update-in`) with `[1 ...]` it will create/update the map entry with key=1.

```clj
| | ks=> [1]
| (assoc-in {:a :b} ks 42)=> {:a :b, 1 42}
| | ks=> [1 :both-unconf]
| (assoc-in {:a :b} ks 42)=> {:a :b, 1 {:both-unconf 42}}
| | ks=> [1 :both-unconf 0]
| (assoc-in {:a :b} ks 42)=> {:a :b, 1 {:both-unconf {0 42}}}
| | ks=> [1 :both-unconf 0 0]
| (assoc-in {:a :b} ks 42)=> {:a :b, 1 {:both-unconf {0 {0 42}}}}
```

Now change your top level structure into a vector, with the second element as a map:

```clj
[:a {:both-unconf [[41 43]]}]
```

```clj
| | ks=> [1]
| (assoc-in [:a #] ks 42)=> [:a 42]
| | ks=> [1 :both-unconf]
| (assoc-in [:a #] ks 42)=> [:a {:both-unconf 42}]
| | ks=> [1 :both-unconf 0]
| (assoc-in [:a #] ks 42)=> [:a {:both-unconf [42]}]
| | ks=> [1 :both-unconf 0 0]
| (assoc-in [:a #] ks 42)=> [:a {:both-unconf [[42 43]]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have obtained the required output by:
(reset! prob-cond (first @prob-cond))
(swap! prob-cond #(update-in % [1 :both-unconf 0 0] (constantly 22)))